# DatabaseError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str)

Tags: python, sql, django

I am trying to encrypt a value in Django but I always get a database error. I guess it does not want to store 8-bit strings in the database. is there a way around it? I am using SQlite on my local machine and postgreSQL in production. Also, here is my code

```
def set_message(self, raw_message):
    last_four = raw_message[len(raw_message)-4:len(raw_message)]
    rest = '*'
    for n in range(0,len(raw_message)-5):
        rest=rest+'*'
    self.message_string = rest+str(last_four)

    extra_words = len(raw_message) % 8 #since Strings for DES must be a multiple of 8 in length

    add_words_length = 8 - extra_words

    for x in range(0,add_words_length):
        raw_message = raw_message + 'X'

    obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_ECB)

    encrypt_raw_message=obj.encrypt(raw_message)

    self.message = encrypt_raw_message

    self.save()
```